# Помогите понять разницу между spin waits и spin rounds

Tags: mysql

Читая [статью](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/09/02/understand-innodb-spin-waits-win-a-percona-live-ticket/) о `MySql`, я хотела выяснить значение `spin waits` и `spin rounds`. Если я правильно перевела эту статью, то получается:

`Mutex spin waits` - количество раз, которое поток пытался получить мьютекс и мьютекс не был доступен (поток ждал в состоянии spin-wait).
`rounds` - количество циклов, которое поток проводил в состоянии spin-wait, проверяя мьютекс.
`OS waits` - количество раз, когда поток прекращал spin-waiting и засыпал.

Но в примере `spin waits` < `rounds`, что говорит о том, что мой перевод неверен. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что означают значения `spin waits` и `spin rounds` и в чём между ними разница.

Comment: В примере `Mutex spin waits 5_870_888, rounds 19_812_448, OS waits 375285`. Rounds - больше. Можно еще посмотреть исходники от вашей версии. Для [5.5](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.5/storage/innobase/sync/sync0sync.c) первое число - количество вызовов `mutex_spin_wait`, второе - количество оборотов цикла внутри `mutex_spin_wait` в ожидании освобождения mutex.

Comment: @zRrr, да, это опечатка, я имела в виду что `spin waits` < `rounds`. Можно подробнее про различие между этими значениями?